# How to calculate the max / ranking among multi-columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data format:

```
    col_a  col_b col_c
0    10     12     11
1     8      6     99
```

And I would like to be the following format:

```
    col_a  col_b col_c  rank_1  rank_2  rank_3
0    10     12     11    10       11      12
1     8      6     99    6        8       99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` and `concat`:

```
print (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df,axis=1),columns=[f"rank_{n}" for n in range(1,4)])],axis=1))

   col_a  col_b  col_c  rank_1  rank_2  rank_3
0     10     12     11      10      11      12
1      8      6     99       6       8      99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(**pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.columns)+1)).add_prefix('rank_'))                                                               


   col_a  col_b  col_c  rank_1  rank_2  rank_3
0     10     12     11      10      11      12
1      8      6     99       6       8      99
```